# jQuery if Cookie Value does not exist of multiple IndexOf's

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies, indexof

I've got a cookie I am creating with jQuery named 'testCookie'.  I want to check to see if any of these VALUES DO NOT exist, if they do NOT (or are equal to or less than -1) I want to do something, the code below currently does nothing and it assumes as if the code isn't even there and loads everything after the if-statement regardless of cookies value, any ideas?

```
if ($.cookie('testCookie').indexOf('shopping','pricegrabber','nextag','shopzilla')<=-1) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `indexOf` function can only take one string at a time. To do this you would need to have multiple clauses in your `if` statement, joined with `&&`:

`if(cookieValue.indexOf('shopping') == -1 && cookieValue.indexOf('pricegrabber') == -1)`

You can add all of your conditions into that `if` statement. The `&&` means "if this and this" etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax of `indexOf()` is like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].indexOf('b'); // returns 1
```

you can use jQuery's `.inArray()` method:

```
$.inArray('b', ['a','b','c','d']); // returns 1
```

---

if `$.cookie('testCookie')` returns string you can check it like this:

```
if (['grabber','nextag','shopzilla'].indexOf($.cookie('testCookie')) == -1)  {
    // your code
}
```

or

```
if ($.inArray($.cookie('testCookie', ['grabber','nextag','shopzilla']) == -1) {
    // your code
}
```